# Why is JIT part of Execution engine of JVM?

Tags: java, jvm, classloader, jit

Following is the flow of a java program execution:

**Bytecode (Javac) -> ClassLoader -> Execution Engine (JIT).**

When the source code is compiled and classloader feeds the bytecode to execution engine to interpret and run the program, why the Just-In-Time (JIT) compiler present in an execution engine when there is nothing to compile?

Comment: There is bytecode to compile.

Comment: This information is about 20 years out of date. JITs were a feature of early JVMs and indeed there was a short lived market in external vendors supplying them: Symantec for example. The JIT was long ago replaced by the HotSpot JVM which works on a different principle altogether.

Comment: @user207421 How is Hotspot using a "different principle altogether"? It compiles bytecode "just in time" into native code. JIT is very much an essential feature of all current JVM.

Comment: @user207421 I suggest you read the first paragraph of the [Wikipedia page on HotSpot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HotSpot) to learn that JIT is indeed involved.

Comment: @Thilo No, it compiles bytecode that has already been executed 10,000 times, or whatever the heuristics are. The problem with JIts was that they compiled everything, 'just in time' as you say, which is therefore before any statistics have been gathered; , 'sprayed code everywhere'; used lots of memory; and wasted a lot of time compiling things that didn't contribute significantly to execution time.

Comment: @BasilBourque I'm not interested in errors in Wikipedia. See [Wikipeda is not a reliable source.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Wikipedia_is_not_a_reliable_source) I was around at the time HotSpot superseded JITs. I remember. Sun changed the name to express the fact that a different principle was being employed, and the one thing you cannot call that principle is 'just in time'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bytecode contains abstract instructions for the [Java virtual machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode). The instructions are not directly executable by conventional machines. The JIT step compiles this abstract bytecode into concrete machine code that can be executed by the machine's CPU.

Comment: One could do this compilation to native code theoretically outside of the execution engine as well (for example as part of the deployment/installation process), but then it is no longer JIT (that would be AOT - Ahead of Time).

Comment: Or one could do completely without compilation to native code, and use a purely emulating/interpreting execution engine, but that is very slow. (Initial versions of the JDK worked like that, before there was Hotspot).

Comment: JIT is a performance optimization and isn't strictly needed for executing "abstract instructions". The interpreter executes byte code by doing the translation to the machine-specific instructions on the fly; often times this is sufficient but when the JVM runtime decides (based on profiling) that some method or loop is "hot enough" then it will compile it to the machine code to avoid interpreter step which slows it down.